# Question on matrix over matrix derivation

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, index-notation

Consider recursive relations
$$\mathbf{H}_k=\sigma(\mathbf{Z}_k),\ \mathbf{Z}_k=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{H}_{k-1}\mathbf{W}_k$$
where $\mathbf{Z}_k\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n_k}$, $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $\mathbf{H}_{k-1}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times o_k}$, $\mathbf{W}_k\in\mathbb{R}^{o_k\times n_k}$, $\sigma$ is an element-wise function, and $1\leq k\leq K$. Also, let $L=f(\mathbf{Z}_K)$ where $L\in \mathbb{R}$, and $f$ is a function $f:\mathbb R^{m\times n_K}\to \mathbb R$

**Problem:**

Given $\mathbf{E}_K:=\partial L/\partial \mathbf{Z}_K$, derive a relation to compute $\partial L/\partial \mathbf{W}_k$ for $1\leq k \leq K$.

---

**My attempt:**

Using the chain rule of calculus, I can write the derivative as
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}_{k}}=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{k}} \frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}_{k}}{\partial \mathbf{W}_{k}}$$
For the first term in the RHS, in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603376), we derived the recursive relation
$$\mathbf{E}_{k-1}=\mathbf{A}^T \mathbf{E}_{k} \mathbf{W}_{k}^T \odot \mathbf{S}_{k-1}$$
where $\mathbf{S}_k=\sigma'(\mathbf{Z}_{k})$. I can derive the second term in RHS using index notation. Let
$${Z_{(k)}}_{i p}=\sum_{j, \ell} A_{i j} {H_{(k-1)}}_{j \ell} {W_{(k)}}_{\ell p}$$
Thus
$$\frac{\partial {Z_{(k)}}_{i p}}{\partial {W_{(k)}}_{a b}}=\delta_{b p} \sum_j A_{i j} {H_{(k-1)}}_{j a}$$

---

**Question:**

I’m having trouble turning the derivative $\partial {Z_{(k)}}_{i p}/\partial {W_{(k)}}_{a b}$ into matrix representation and deriving a final matrix form for $\partial L/\partial \mathbf{W}_k$ in terms of $\mathbf{E}_k$.

Answer (score 2):

Following [Greg's answer&notations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603376), it holds
$$
dL 
= \mathbf{E}_k: d\mathbf{Z}_k 
= (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{H}_{k-1})^T\mathbf{E}_k: d\mathbf{W}_k
$$
The gradient is computed as
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mathbf{W}_k} 
= (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{H}_{k-1})^T\mathbf{E}_k
$$

Comment: Thanks. A few notes: I think by dE you mean dL? Then, do you use "$dZ_k=AH_{k-1}dW_k$" to proceed? If so, (and I have made the same comment for Greg's answer as well) I'm confused as to why do we use "$dZ_k=AdH_{k-1}W_k$" at one place and use "$dZ_k=AH_{k-1}dW_k$" in the next step?

Comment: I have corrected for the loss function. Regarding your question, $H_{k-1}$ does not depend on $W_k$ so it is supposed to be constant. We can thus write $dZ_k=AH_{k-1}dW_k$ and proceed further.